# Friendly category URLs - generated only when adding, blocked when editing (PrestaShop)

Tags: javascript, url, prestashop, smarty

I have a problem with adding functionality to PrestaShop (1.7.8.9): I want a friendly URL to be created when adding a new category, but not to change when editing an existing one (e.g. changing h1/title) - only manual change is possible.

I've been looking for a solution on many sites, but none of them work.

I'll tell you right away that I cleared the cache.

Please help!

Peace!

I tried editing the file:

```
Backoffice\themes\default\template\helpers\form\form.tpl
in this place:
onkeyup="if (isArrowKey(event)) return ;updateFriendlyURL();"
```

I tried editing in the file:

```
js\admin.js
functions:
copyMeta2friendlyURL(), updateFriendlyURLByName(), updateFriendlyURL(), updateLinkRewrite()
```

...

I looked in /class, in /controllers, in JS files... and nothing.
Maybe someone can tell me where to look for this damn thing?

Comment: You should develop a module and execute your code on hookcategorybeforeupdate (something like this) everytime you pick the old value of friendly url array (is multilang) and overwrite the new value. You should be able to find both on the hook params.